# Why doesn't my Feed-Forward NN work with varying inputs?

Tags: c#, neural-network, backpropagation, feed-forward

I decided to create a feedforward Neural Network without using any libraries. I am fairly new to the subject and completely self-trained.

My Neural Network uses backpropagation to set the weights and the activation function between all layers (input-hidden1-output) is a Sigmoid function.
Let's say that I try to solve a basic problem like the XOr logic gate problem with my NN. Whenever i use the complete training set (all the possible combinations of 1s and 0s) my NN cannot set the weights in such a way that it could produce the desired output. Seemingly it always stops at the middle. (output is ~0.5 in all cases) 
On the other hand, when I only iterate one type of input (Let's say 0 and 1) it quickly learns.

Is there a problem in my cost function, number of nodes, hidden layers or what? I would appreciate some guiding words!

Comment: Since this is not about specific languages or programming and more about machine learning itself, this question might be better suited for https://stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

XOR problem is not linearly separable and makes single layer perceptron unfit. However, in your network addition of hidden layer makes the network to capture non-linear features, which makes it fine.

The most plausible reason for the poor performance of the network would be due to tortuous initial phase to learn the problem. So increasing the iterations would solve the problem.

And one more possible thing to try is by the smooth nonlinearity of XOR, so the role of bias is crucial as the translation parameter and as important as weights (which you did not mention)

Comment: I tried increasing the number of iterations but it didn't work. I also use biases so that can also be crossed out.

Comment: I think, "Seemingly it always stops at the middle. (output is ~0.5 in all cases) ", from this statement, `weights * input` gives zero, which may occur due to input data being 0's. Are you using batch wise training and the mean of all loss?

Comment: It is around 0.5 and not exactly that much so the input is definitely not 0. What do you mean by "mean of all loss"?

Answer (score -1):

XOR can't be solved with one hidden layer. Because you can't separate your labels (0 and 1) with just one line. You can separate them with two lines and then use AND gate (another hidden layer) to find their common area.
See this post for clarification: https://medium.com/@jayeshbahire/the-xor-problem-in-neural-networks-50006411840b

Comment: This is incorrect, a NN can be learned with one hidden layer, it even says so in the article you linked

Comment: I read the very same article prior to posting this question. It does not specifically state that more than one hidden layer is necessary. It even uses pictures of NNs with 3 layers. Furthermore, the book "Introduction to Neural Networks for C#, Second Edition" also solves this problem with 1 hidden layer.